# Will the bluetooth server thread work in standby?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

I have a Service and I created a AcceptThread (like http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) for accept incoming bluetooth connections.
Will it work when the device go to standby?

Comment: hay attila ..i am also searching for the same ..have u got any solution for this? do u using service class in background of application for notify when we are in home screen and any other device want to communicate with us...

Answer (score 0):

I am working with threads inside a service and, although i've not worked with bluetooth, i think that this could help you.

When phone gone in standby mode, the cpu will stop working, and so any other thread/application/service will stop, too.

I solved this by using PowerManager, like here:

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
 wl.acquire();
   ..CPU will stay on during this section..
 wl.release();
```

Hope this will help you!